# How would I pass a 2d user inputted array from a function into main()?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program using arrays and I'm not sure how to pass a 2d array from a function into main(). I would like to set a 2d array in main() from the output array of the read_matrix() function.

```
void read_matrix();

int main()
{
    //reads a matrix from user input
    read_matrix();

    new_matrix[][] = matrix[n_i][n_i] //I would like to set a new 2d array in main() from the 2d array
                                      //output from the read_matrix() function.
    return 0;
}


//reads a matrix from user input
void read_matrix()
{
    //initialise variables
    int n_i = 0;
    int row;
    int column;

    //dimensions of matrix
    printf("Enter a value for the dimensions of a square matrix: \n");
    printf(">>");
    scanf("%i", &n_i);

    //initialise matrix
    int matrix[n_i][n_i];

    //elements of matrix
    for(row = 0; row < n_i; ++row)
    {
        for(column = 0; column < n_i; ++column)
        {
            printf("Enter a value for the [%i][%i] element: \n", row, column);
            printf(">>");
            scanf("%i", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind VLA's is considered a bad practice, you should check out malloc and free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate your matrix on the heap and you should return it as well as its dimensions:

```
int **read_matrix(int *n_i);

int main()
{
    //reads a matrix from user input
    int n_i;
    int **matrix = read_matrix(&n_i);

    //do something 

    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}

//reads a matrix from user input
int **read_matrix(int *n_i)
{
    //initialise variables
    int *n_i = 0;
    int row;
    int column;

    //dimensions of matrix
    printf("Enter a value for the dimensions of a square matrix: \n");
    printf(">>");
    scanf("%i", &n_i);

    //initialise matrix
    int **matrix = malloc(n_i * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_i; ++i)
        matrix[i] = malloc(n_i * sizeof(int));

    //elements of matrix
    for(row = 0; row < n_i; ++row)
    {
        for(column = 0; column < n_i; ++column)
        {
            printf("Enter a value for the [%i][%i] element: \n", row, column);
            printf(">>");
            scanf("%i", &matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a big problem here. An array when passed or returned to a function loses its length value. So you will need to return both the dimension of matrix and the matrix itself. Now, C does not support returning two values. So one choice you have it to wrap it in a structure and return the structure.

However, that is an ugly solution. Also, you should not pass/return values like matrices by value but with pointer because of the size constraint of stack.